# How to get current Website ID in the Admin Panel?

Tags: magento2, adminhtml

I working with a custom extension related with multiple websites. I face with an issue, define a script code execute in the Admin Panel by getting Website Id. I expected result `website_id` like 0 (default ID in `store_website` table). But when I using this function below it always return 1.

```
/** @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface */
$this->_storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId(); //return 1, expect 0
$this->_storeManager->getWebsite()->getId(); //return 1
```

> **My Question**: Any way to get current `website_id` in the Admin Panel or define a function run in `adminhtml` area?
>
> *Note:* *This function needs to work on both the frontend and backend.*

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: check first multi website exist or not in your store.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The general idea is to pass the scope, chosen, through the request parameter.

I think you should use the similar code like in the product edit action:

```
/** @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager */
$storeManager = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$storeId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('store', 0);
$store = $storeManager->getStore($storeId);
$storeManager->setCurrentStore($store->getCode());
```

In this case `$store->getWebsiteId()` should be actual (selected) website id. But this can be done only in case you use the store block which works in the same way as a standard magento block (to select a store scope):

[image: store selector]

Here is my result in the example when I select the default store view (id == 1):

[image: 1 store view debug example]

and here is for the default global scope (*All Store Views*, website id is 0):

[image: global scope debug example]

---

#### Update:

You can add a method like this in the helper and use it where you want:

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\App\State
 */
protected $state;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
 */
protected $storeManager;

/**
 * Data constructor.
 * @param Context $context
 * @param \Magento\Framework\App\State $state
 * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
 */
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\App\State $state,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
) {
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->state = $state;
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
}

/**
 * @return int
 */
public function resolveCurrentWebsiteId()
{
    if ($this->state->getAreaCode() == \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_ADMINHTML) {
        // in admin area
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request */
        $request = $this->_request;
        $storeId = (int) $request->getParam('store', 0);
    } else {
        // frontend area
        $storeId = true; // get current store from the store resolver
    }

    $store = $this->storeManager->getStore($storeId);
    $websiteId = $store->getWebsiteId();

    return $websiteId;
}
```

**Result** should be like this:

1. Backend without scope selector - **0**

   [image: backed without store selector]
2. Backed with scope selector - **selected website id or 0 if nothing selected (All Store Views)**

   [image: backend with store selector]
3. Frontend - **current website id**

   [image: frontend]

---

#### If you are looking for the short-way on the frontend:

You can use the `Magento\Store\Model\StoreResolver` class for that purpose:

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreResolver
 */
private $storeResolver;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreResolver $storeResolver
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreResolver $storeResolver
) {
    $this->storeResolver = $storeResolver;
}

/**
 * Returns the current store id, if it can be detected or default store id
 * 
 * @return int|string
 */
public function getCurrentStoreId()
{
    return $this->storeResolver->getCurrentStoreId();
}
```

It is correctly detects the currently selected store view on the frontend area, but useless for the admin area.

Comment: It's working in the Admin Panel. However, I want to it will  get current website in the frontend. This function always return `website_id = 0`

Comment: This function needs to work on both the frontend and backend.

Comment: @Bill Can you clarify in which place you are trying to get the store id? Is it plugin or maybe observer?

Comment: Hi @Siarhey Uchukhlebau, I want to get it from a class. This class may be called from any other class e.g: Controller, Model, Helper, Block, ...

Comment: @Bill I updated the answer, check please

Comment: I appreciated your answer, but it doesn't simple. If don't any other answers, I will bounty point for you

Comment: @Bill Ok, I think there is no simple solution :(

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve the ID for configuration scope selected in the Admin AREA, then try checking the request parameters for the value of the current configuration scope.
`/**
* @var RequestInterface
*/
protected $_request;

```
/**
 * @param RequestInterface $request
 */
public function __construct(
    RequestInterface $request
)
{
    $this->_request = $request;
}

/**
 * @return bool|void
 */
public function getWebsiteId()
{
    return $websiteId = $this->_request->getParam('website');
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get current website id of selected website in admin panel

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Namespace\Controller\Index;

class Index
{
    protected $state;
    
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request,
        \Magento\Framework\App\State $state
    ){
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->state = $state;
    }

    public function execute() {
        if ($this->state->getAreaCode() == \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_ADMINHTML) {
            // in admin area
            /** @var \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request */
            $request = $this->request;
            $websiteId = (int) $request->getParam('website', 0);
        }
        
        echo $websiteId;
        die;
    }
}
```