# Creating order in Magento 2 backend, how to find out the store?

Tags: magento2, multistore, payment-gateway, store-id

I have a payment module used in Magento 2 backend order creation.

In Magento 2 the administrator first chooses the store where the order is to be created. However, when reading **configuration** I always get configuration from **store 1**.
Also using `\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface` I always get `store ID 1`.

How can I find out which store the order is being created to?

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you will find the the answer for your question [here](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/147424/how-to-get-current-website-id-in-the-admin-panel/147772#147772)

Comment: Nope, tried and getting store id 0. The website selection is different for backend orders.

Answer (score 4):

As you can see in the corresponding controller (`Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Create`) you should use next code to get the requested store id:

```
$storeId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('store_id');
```

Or you can get the `store_id` from the current quote session (just add the `Magento\Backend\Model\Session\Quote` in di):

```
/** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\Session\Quote $session */
$session->getStoreId()
```

Comment: getParam does not work in an observer, $session->getStoreId() does.

Comment: @TeroLahtinen If my answer has helped you, please accept it.

Comment: I have to face this issue still using this class Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface::store => store->getStore()->getStoreId();

It return 1, when I refresh the page then it return correct selected store id in order create page screen